# cannot open dataframe even though file uploaded

Tags: python, dataframe

EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757.xls(application/vnd.ms-excel) - 7188992 bytes, last modified: 10/14/2023 - 100% done
Saving EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757.xls to EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757 (2).xls

```
print(uploaded)
import io
data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757.xls']))
data.head()
```

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-d90228905557> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 print(uploaded)
      2 import io
----> 3 data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757.xls']))
      4 data.head()

KeyError: 'EXTR_CA_VAMS01_12863757.xls'
```

i tried restarting the computer

Comment: This error seems not related to the dataframe, it's for the variable 'uploaded', as you have added the code print(uploaded), can you provide more info on his type and his content, is it a dictionary